# JFileChooser for Python?

Tags: java, python, jfilechooser

I was wondering if there is something similar to Java's `JFileChooser` for Python?

`JFileChooser` is a graphical front end to choose a file.

Preferably something that is already with Python. Maybe with Tkinter.

Comment: A quick explanation of what JFileChooser is might help get some better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something that doesn't require wxPython and sticks with the standard Python libs, you can use the tkFileDialog.askopenfilename() method:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
print askopenfilename()
```

Comment: Maybe this worked for python2. But for python3 you need the answer of A. L. Strine.

Answer (score 4):

wxPython (www.wxpython.org) provides the wx.FileDialog class which will give you a native file selection dialog on any of the supported platforms (Mac, Linux or Windows).

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way I ever found to do this (using PyGTK and [Kiwi](http://async.com.br/projects/kiwi)):

```
from kiwi.ui.dialogs import open as open_dialog

chosen_path = open_dialog('Select a file', folder='/start/folder')

if chosen_path is not None:
    # do something ...
```

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on your windowing toolkit. wxWidgets provides the [wxFileDialog](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxfiledialog.html).

Answer (score 1):

For python 3 what you're looking for is tkinter.filedialog, and all that comes with it. Here's a short program that opens and then prints a TXT file of the user's choosing via askopenfilename:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.update()
pathString = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files","*.txt")])
if pathString:
    openFile = open(pathString, 'r')
    fileString = openFile.read()
    print(fileString)
root.destroy()
```

Output is whatever is in the selected file.

Comment: For python3 you need to check for definition of `pathString` (not for empty string): `if pathString:` (see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47067803/1908115 )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to take a look at Jython.