# Tkinter askopenfilename not returning as expected when user clicks "Cancel."

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

According to the documentation, filedialog.askopenfilename() is supposed to return an empty string if the user clicks "Cancel," but it's not doing that, and I can't figure out what it's actually returning.

I made this little test program, and the behavior is identical to my actual project:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

name = filedialog.askopenfilename()
if name == '':
    print("Nothing chosen")
else:
    print(name)
```

What ends up printing when the user clicks cancel is a pair of empty parentheses ()

Replacing '' with '()' does not change anything.

Any help figuring out what is happening is appreciated.  Thank you.

UPDATE: Got it working thanks to @PaulRooney's suggestion, but now, the first time I run this section of code (in my full project), it returns the empty tuple.  For every subsequent run, it returns an empty string.

Simply checking for both works for what I need, but it's bizarre behavior.

I'm using Python 3 on Linux Mint.

Comment: This is working as intended for me.  What operating system are you on?

Comment: Can you cite the documentation you are using? Is it effbot? The function seems to be returning an empty tuple. Perhaps this is a change between py2 and py3. The comparison to `'()'` wont work, as that's a string, not a tuple. Instead try `if name == ():` (without the quotes) or more idiomatically `if not name:`. Those both work for me.

Comment: @PaulRooney That did it.  Thanks for the help.

For reference: I'm using python3 on Linux Mint.

Comment: Now I'm getting some more odd behavior with it.  Updated the question.

Comment: If you just do `if not name:` does this not handle both instances? It is odd that it does that. I can see it too. I guess it's just one the quirks of the python/tk interface.

Comment: @PaulRooney Nope.  using `if not name:` doesn't appear to work for me.

Comment: Thats odd as it definitely works for me. It should return false for an empty string or an empty tuple. See [this](https://ideone.com/sfq8u1) demo code (obviously it doesn't run in the browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if name will work just fine.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

name = filedialog.askopenfilename()
if name:
    print(name)
else:
    print("Nothing chosen")
```

Comment: This works for me, but the suggestion of `if not name:` does not.  I'll accept this as the answer and just be glad it works, but I'm still greatly confused.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't see this post till after I answered an older but similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47436993/4358942)!

Basically, clicking **Cancel** will return an empty string...
Unless you actually select/highlight a file first and then click cancel.
This seems to return an empty tuple!!!

(I didn't try with initialdir and initialfile options but am guessing they also cause an empty tuple to be returned... at least initially?)

Using python 2.6.6 (IDK, ask RedHat)
Running the following code produces the subsequent results

`f_picked = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
test = type(f_picked)
print (test)`
Results:
`<type 'unicode'>` # Nothing selected, **Cancel** clicked
`<type 'tuple'>` # File selected, **Cancel** clicked
`<type 'str'>` # File selected, **OK** clicked
`<type 'tuple'>` # Multiple files selected, **OK** clicked

Answer (score 1):

I'm using python 3.8 and from my experience
`filedialog` when is closed does not always return an empty string, to handle it you can use the `type` keyword to identify the type of data from `filedialog` and then use the `if` statement to handle it

```
    from tkinter import filedialog

    filePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    if str(type(filePath))=="<class 'tuple'>" or filePath == '':
        # This part will be executed when the user cancels or exit
        print('filePath is not contain path')

    else:
        print('your path',filePath)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have a `File -> Open` menu item that displays an askopenfilename dialogue. I am finding that with `python 2.7` and `3.6`, the *first time* I use the dialogue and select `Cancel` or close the dialogue from the window border, it returns an empty tuple instead of `''`. Every time thereafter the dialogue returns `''` on `Cancel` or window close.

Perhaps this is some sort of feature but it feels like a bug, particularly for this dialogue that doesn't support selection of multiple files. An empty tuple would make sense from askopenfilenames.

I've settled on this simple test and cleanup for the file name returned by the askopenfilename dialogue:

```
if str(filename) == '()':
    filename = ''
```

Comment: I don't think this works, because one can get  `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str`

Answer (score -1):

Hmm... Make sure you are using using Python 3 because this won't work on Python 2
It worked for me, when I changed the brackets to "" (i'm on Python 2)