# Minimal wx.FileDialog example freezes program

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I'm writing a new application.

I used to work with python 2.x and wxPython some years ago, now I got Python 3.7.0 and wxPythonPhoenix 4.0.4 msw (alas).

When I try to use wx.FileDialog with ShowModal, the program freezes.

I did not find any previous question about this.
I used (and reduced for the MWE) code from wxWiki like [this](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.FileDialog.html?highlight=filedialog).

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title, size=(400, 200))
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        openItem = fileMenu.Append(-1, "&Open...\tCtrl-O", "Open a new recipe")
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, openItem)
    def OnOpen(self, event):
        # otherwise ask the user what new file to open
        with wx.FileDialog(self, "Open XYZ file", wildcard="XYZ files (*.xyz)|*.xyz",
                           style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST) as fileDialog:

            if fileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
                return     # the user changed their mind

        #you'll never get here      

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "test")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I really don't get it, moreover the code actually worked for a couple of times.

Comment: The MWE works as expected in Win10 and OS 10.14.4.

Comment: I did not mention the fact that I rebooted at least three times before posting this question.
Anyway this afternoon is working again, so it seem to be a MSW issue, still annoying, but nothing I can cope with.

Comment: Maybe the `ID = -1` you use several times, is the problem. When I do this at the `fileMenu.Append(-1, …` my menu stopps showing the keyboard shortcut. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started from the minimal working example I copied from the [wxpython wiki](https://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#Working_with_Windows).

Then I reduced it to your minimal working example. I think the problem might be the `-1` value of the id of the `fileMenu.Append(-1, …`.

### Smallest Minimal Working Example (MWE):

```
import wx                                                                                                                           

app = wx.App()
with wx.FileDialog(None, "Open XYZ file", wildcard="XYZ files (*.xyz)|*.xyz",
                           style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST) as fileDialog:

    if fileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
        print("the user changed their mind")
    else:
        # Proceed loading the file chosen by the user
        pathname = fileDialog.GetPath()
        try:
            with open(pathname, 'r') as file:
                print(file.read())
        except IOError:
            wx.LogError("Cannot open file '%s'." % newfile)
```

### Based on your code, works perfectly (always):

```
import wx                                                                                                                           

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title, size=(400, 200))
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        openItem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "&Open"," Open a file to edit")
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, openItem)
    def OnOpen(self, event):
        # otherwise ask the user what new file to open
        with wx.FileDialog(self, "Open XYZ file", wildcard="XYZ files (*.xyz)|*.xyz",
                           style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST) as fileDialog:

            if fileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
                return     # the user changed their mind

            # Proceed loading the file chosen by the user
            pathname = fileDialog.GetPath()
            try:
                with open(pathname, 'r') as file:
                    #self.doLoadDataOrWhatever(file)
                    print(file.read()) # see, it works!
            except IOError:
                wx.LogError("Cannot open file '%s'." % newfile)


app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "test")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

### More beautiful and with some explanations:

```
import wx                                                                                                                           

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):

        # A "-1" in the size parameter instructs wxWidgets to use the default size.
        # In this case, we select 200px width and the default height.
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,-1))

        # Setting up the menu.
        filemenu= wx.Menu()
        menuOpen = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "&Open"," Open a file to edit")

        # Creating the menubar.
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu,"&File") # Adding the "filemenu" to the MenuBar
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.

        # Events.
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, menuOpen)

        self.Show()

    def OnOpen(self,e):
        """ Open a file"""
        with wx.FileDialog(self, "Open XYZ file", wildcard="XYZ files (*.xyz)|*.xyz",
                           style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST) as fileDialog:

            if fileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
                return     # the user changed their mind

            # Proceed loading the file chosen by the user
            pathname = fileDialog.GetPath()
            try:
                with open(pathname, 'r') as file:
                    #self.doLoadDataOrWhatever(file)
                    print(file.read())
            except IOError:
                wx.LogError("Cannot open file '%s'." % newfile)


app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "test")
app.MainLoop()
```

### See also

More GUI options for file dialogs: [JFileChooser for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/433945/1908115)